# Using a hex int from a edit box (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi

I've just written a small programme which should read 3 values (window name, base address, value) from edit boxes in a window. Using the window name and the value in `WriteProcessMemory()` works, but the base address won't work.

```
TCHAR windowName[100];
int baseAddress;
int replaceValue;
HWND window;
DWORD procId;
HANDLE proc;

GetDlgItemText(hwnd, 1, windowName, 100); // works correctly
replaceValue = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, 3, NULL, TRUE); // works also
baseAddress = GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, 2, NULL, TRUE); // doesn't get the right int when input is hex

window = FindWindow(NULL, windowName);
GetWIndowThreadProcessId(window, &procId);
proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procId);
WriteProcessMemory(proc, (LPVOID)baseAddress, &replaceValue, sizeof(replaveValue), NULL); // works when baseAddress is dec
CloseHandle(proc);
```

All in all, it doesn't work when the baseAddress is in hex.

Comment: *"doesn't get the right int when input is hex"* well why would it? `GetDlgItemInt` only knows base 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says, with my emphasis:

> The GetDlgItemInt function retrieves the text of the specified control by sending the control a WM_GETTEXT message. The function translates the retrieved text by stripping any extra spaces at the beginning of the text and then converting the **decimal digits**. The function stops translating when it reaches the end of the text or encounters a nonnumeric character.

This function interprets the text in the specified window as decimal.

If you wish to interpret as hexadecimal then you must code that yourself. Retrieve the text with `GetDlgItemText`. Then convert that to an integer using a conversion function that interprets the text as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1):

I would just get the text of the control with `GetDlgItemText` then convert it to `int` with another function like `strtol` from the C standard library for example; just anything that does a text-to-integer conversion with support for multiple bases. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: Thanks! I will try it later.